# Tokenizing Text Held in a Rope Data Structure

Tags: data-structures, text-processing

I am building a text editor which makes use of a [Ragel based tokenizer](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ragel) to support syntax highlighting.  I am considering the use of a [rope data structure](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rope_(data_structure)) to support efficient modifications and undo/redo operations.  Is there a standard approach for tokenizing or searching text contained in this type of data structure?  Some characters can cause the tokenizer to consume the rest of the stream.

Comment: While I have heard of ropes before, I have never actually needed to use them directly: this is an interesting question. Are there any constraints on what characters are in each node in the rope? Perhaps each token should be its own node?

Comment: I may be tokenizing at too high a level and have to revisit that area.  Rather than having a single token consume an entire comment or string; it is probably wiser to have a begin and end token for those constructs.  The renderer could then simply render based on state; now, it renders characters with a style based on the token type it belongs to.  I may be able to have a rope that keeps track of whole tokens rather than segments of text.  But, I am still curious about operations like searching efficiently.  Would I have to reconstruct the string for each search?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm familiar with the underlying state-machine approach described in your link --- it's been around for decades. It can tokenise/categorise any stream of text that supports a get-next-character operation.

I'm familiar with ropes in the context of a text editor. The usual purpose (as I know it) is to break the strings into portions that have the same display attributes: colour, font, link, line breaks etc. This works well for both editing and display. The major operations are: insert character; delete character; delete token; cut and paste. Maintaining the rope is not easy.

It's not obvious from your question whether you expect the tokeniser to generate the rope. Is it a rope of tokens, where each token has its own display attributes? I would be troubled that editing and tokenisation could interfere with each other. Things like quotes and comments can reach a long way.

No, I don't there is a standard way of combining these ideas. I suspect the right idea is for the tokeniser to generate/regenerate the rope, immediately for the on-screen portion and in the background for the rest. Edits should affect the rope (only) with a short delay before retokenising. The tokenising needs to be interruptible too.

It feels like a reasonable approach, but I'm sure there are many challenges in making it work well. You might want to read some source code (Eclipse? Netbeans?) to see how others do it.